# Postgres running on kubernetes looses data upon Pod recreation or cluster reboot

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-storage

I have the *postgres* container running in a `Pod` on **GKE** and a `PersistentVolume` set up to store the data. However, all of the data in the database is lost if the cluster reboots or if the `Pod` is deleted.

If I run `kubectl delete <postgres_pod>` to delete the existing `Pod` and check the newly created (by *kubernetes*) `Pod` to replace the deleted one, the respective database has not the data that it had before the `Pod` being deleted.

Here are the *yaml* files I used to deploy *postgres*.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: custom-storage
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-volume-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: custom-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:11.5
        resources: {}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        env:
          - name: POSTGRES_DB
            value: "dbname"
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            value: "user"
          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            value: "password"
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/
            name: postgresdb
      volumes:
        - name: postgresdb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-volume-claim
```

I double checked that the `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` has value `Retain`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the cluster creating a new volume each time you delete a pod?  Check with `kubectl get pv`.

Is this a multi-zone cluster?  Your storage class is not provisionig regional disks, so you might be getting a new disk when the pod moves from one zone to another.

Possibly related to your problem, the postgres container reference recommends mounting at `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` and setting the `PGDATA` env variable:
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres#pgdata

Comment: Thank you for your response.It was due to the mounting path and the `PGDATA` env variable. [This github post](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/263#issuecomment-460998040) shows the correct values for the `PGDATA` and mounting path.